# Collections of classified sample sentences (about certain grammatical feature)

Tags: resource-request

I am trying to find some exhaustive collection of classified sample sentences - passive, with relative clauses, conditionals, and so on. Is this available? It does not have to be online, I am also OK with some published material.

Comment: For which language? What do you want to do with it? Are you aware of Treebanks (e.g. the Penn Treebank) and does a Treebank fulfil your needs?

Comment: @jknappen: it's for English. I want it to generate grammar drills (for EFL). I was not aware of the Penn Treebank, but it seems that's in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

For syntactically annotated sentences, I suggest to get a [treebank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebank), for example the [Penn Treebank](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/ldc99t42).

There is also a great tool called [GrETEL](https://www.clarin.eu/showcase/gretel-search-engine-querying-syntactic-constructions-treebanks) that allows you to enter a sentence (in ordinary language) and query for syntactically similar sentences. GrETEL is supported by the European Language Research Infrastructure [CLARIN](https://www.clarin.eu/).